# is there a way to fix Seymour Duncan Woody HC Hum-Canceling Soundhole Pickup cable?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, pick-ups

A friend that visited the States got it for me, but after half hour of using it I believe the cable got broken. Now it sounds with a buzz everytime I use it.

Is there a way to replace the cable? Since it is a woody box there's no way to open it. Is there anything I can do at all or should I just cry for my broken pickup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the plug end of the pickup. You should be able to unscrew the sleeve from the jack and visually inspect the cable solder ends.  If any one of the ends look shoddy I would try resoldering it.

**Usually a buzz sound indicates a broken or unstable ground in the cable.** Since its hard wired into the pickup you may have it broken inside the pickup. With a little patience though, either problem can be fixed with new solder and/or a new cable.

Even if you require a new cable, it should be replaceable without getting a whole new pickup.

If you do take the chance of repairing it yourself, I highly recommend using a razor blade for easily getting the cable apart.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'll try it out today. I believe the cable is broken inside the pickup so I'll have to get a new cable. I'm gonna take it to a music store today, and I hope they know what to do since they don't sell those pickups where I live. Just in case, do you know how exactly can I get the cable off the pickup? Just use the razor blade?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion for the razor blade was for easier cable replacement.  As far as disassembling the pickup, I am not sure.  I'm looking hard at high-res images of woody pickups.  It appears they are made of out of at least 3 pieces of maple glued together.  With some heat and a little time, you could probably pry them apart to actually get to the connection which may be broken.  Have you inspected the male end of the plug as suggested?  Does any solder or wire look loose?

Comment: yes, the problem is inside. I checked the other side of the plug and everything's fine, problem is inside the pickup :( At music store they told me it had no solution.

Comment: I'll try to find a way to heat it and see if it gets apart. I appreciate your answer and time, thank you very much!

Comment: Good luck, in any case you'll eventually be able to find yourself a replacement cable.  There's no reasonable explanation for why they can't create an acoustic pickup with no cable permanently attached.  How much more is a jack and nut when we're talking hundreds of thousands of products?

Answer (score 0):

These pickups have a major design fault. After examining one with the exact same problem as above, it appears that the screening wire gets broken though because of the inner conductive-rubber sheath pulling back and cutting the copper wire wrap. Once this has happened it's almost impossible to make a reliable repair.

S-D should redesign the thing to have an inbuilt socket or use a different type of cable. One with a more robust screening wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at repairing one here: http://www.thefretboard.co.uk/discussion/63775/seymour-duncan-woody-repair-sparkies-help-required-please

You can get into the with a bit of patience the gooey stuff on the back comes out. It is a bit of a faff though. Pretty poor design.

Comment: Could you summarize the contents of the link here, so that people don't have to follow it for the information? Thanks!